# Basic tuning - note problem with C

Tags: guitar, tuning

I'm starting guitar 2 weeks from now :)   I am fine tuning my guitar.  All the notes are fine except when I hold down the B string to make C it is coming out as C sharp.  D and all the other notes are fine, does anyone have any idea what could cause this and how to fix it.  Thank you

Comment: Are you holding the first fret or the second fret?  Don't forget that "C" is the *same* as "B#" and "Cb" is the same as "B"!!!  So if you're holding the second fret, C# is proper.

Comment: If you *are* holding the first fret, what happens at the fifth fret?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your immediate comments.  I've figured it out now, beginners idiocy.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the B string on the *second* fret, and it still produces a C# note, then there's a fretwire problem - it's too high on the second fret. It's not really a beginner's fix.

Answer (score 0):

If open B is in tune, and it goes C# when you fret it to C, you need to intonate your guitar. If you're using an electric guitar,  you can adjust the saddle away from the neck. You can loosen up the string so that the saddles can move freely when you adjust it.

If you're on an acoustic gear, you might want to bring your gear to a tech/luthier.